# $(window).click(function(e) - identifier of currently clicked element

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(window).click(function(e) {
    alert(e.???);
});
```

How can I check how id, class or other identifiers of the current click?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The event object gives you a `target` property that refers to the actual element clicked, and a `currentTarget` property that refers to the element to which the handler was bound.

Those elements are represented as DOM nodes, which are just objects with their own properties, which enable to you to access certain aspects of the state of the element.

```
$(window).click(function(e) {
    alert(e.target.id); // gives the element's ID 
    alert(e.target.className); // gives the elements class(es)
});
```

Answer (score 5):

http://api.jquery.com/category/events/

and look at event.* - 17

or `console.dir(e);` instead `alert(e);` to see what you have ...

```
$(window).click(function(e) {
    console.dir(e);
});
```